# Preventing an email from being sent to Outlook's Junk folder

Tags: vb.net, outlook, exchange-server

I'm writing an application that creates a word document and emails it to a user from our shared mailbox.  The code works fine, however the message is delivered to the Junk folder instead of the Inbox.

I believe this is because it's coming directly from the email address (mymailbox@company.com), instead of the mailbox name in our Global Address List (My Mailbox).

Is there a way to get VB.Net to recognize my Global Address List so I can send directly from the mailbox name; or is there another solution to this problem?

Comment: no not really you just should include a comment on your email... to avoid this going in your spam, please add us to your contacts..

Comment: what you could do is use mailchimp or something like that to send emails - they never go in spam!

Comment: The problem is that this is an email sent to new hires in our company.  It will literally be the first email they ever receive, so it's very important that it goes to their inbox.

Comment: see this link http://www.interspire.com/content/2006/09/28/improve-your-email-delivery-rates/ and this http://www.allspammedup.com/2009/09/7-ways-to-prevent-your-emails-being-blocked-as-spam/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just why something ends up in the junk mail is something set by the recipient's email client and/or ISP and not something you have control over. You may be able to maximise your chances of appearing to be non-spam by making your email have fewer spammy characteristics - if you could re-cast your sending system to create the message as an email rather than an attachment  this may help.

Comment: This ended up being the closest thing to a solution.  I converted the body of the email to HTML, added some more lines of text, and now Outlook doesn't recognize it as Junk anymore.

Comment: Thanks Austin - actually I missed the fact that you were referring to _internal_ email, but glad I could help

Answer (score 3):

You can set the "from" address in mailmessage.from to the proper email address. However, the "from" address is usually not enough to get an email sent to the spam folder.

There are several steps you can take to make it more likely your email gets through. The links in the comment above Rachel Gallen cover these pretty well.

http://www.allspammedup.com/2009/09/7-ways-to-prevent-your-emails-being-blocked-as-spam/

http://www.interspire.com/content/2006/09/28/improve-your-email-delivery-rates/